# Screen flicker when ups switches to battery

Tags: display, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, external-display

I've bought new monitor. I'm facing flickering issue when lights are gone and my ups switches on battery. I even replaced my cpu with a laptop, the issue is still there. The monitor I was using before was working properly.
I want to know if the issue is with ups or my monitor.

Monitor: Acer et221q

https://www.amazon.in/gp/aw/d/B076PGBM25/ref=mp_s_a_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1579888320&sr=1-4&pi=AC_SX118_SY170_QL70&dpPl=1&dpID=51RL5R0FoFL&ref=plSrch

Comment: So it continues to flicker while on UPS?

Comment: No, Its flicker or become black for 1 second or less and everything the fine there after, till again light is back and ups switches back.

Comment: OK, Model of UPS? How old is it also.

Comment: I bought it 6 months back.

Comment: My ups is intex protector 725. https://www.amazon.in/Intex-1187-3725-0-Protector-725-UPS/dp/B008LNERRK

Comment: My guess is the UPS does not switch fast enough for the new monitor, only way to test is to use a name brand UPS to see if it does the same thing. I prefer APC brand.

Comment: I got it. My cheap hdmi cable had some problem. I bought amazonbasics hdmi cable. Now its working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with cheap hdmi cable, using a good quality amazonbasics cable solved the issue.

Comment: Nice diagnosis! Never would have guessed the hdmi cable.

Comment: @Moab Did you solve it? I have similar issue with an UPS. https://superuser.com/questions/1613252/hdmi-blinks-when-ups-switchs-voltage